# OVS Bridge Inbound broadcast packets dropped when rstp enabled

Tags: openvswitch

I have set up the network through OVS.
However, communication with other PCs is not working normally.

Checking the reason, inbound broadcast packets are dropped.

[image: diagram]

## ovs-vsctl show

```
    Bridge "vmbr1"
        Port "vmbr1"
            Interface "vmbr1"
                type: internal
        Port "enp5s0" <= Trunk Port
            Interface "enp5s0"
        Port "veth1"
            tag: 10
            Interface "veth1"
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.12.0"
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
auto enp5s0
iface enp5s0 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr1

auto veth1
iface veth1 inet static
        address 10.0.0.100/24
        gateway 10.0.0.1
        ovs_type OVSIntPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr1
        ovs_options tag=10

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSBridge
        ovs_ports veth1 enp5s0
        ovs_options rstp_enable=true other_config:rstp-priority=40960
```

### Test-1: Ping from PC to Server

Not working.

# tcpdump -nn -e -i enp5s0

```
05:32:36.472613 aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 64: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.100 tell 10.0.0.200, length 46
```

# tcpdump -nn -i vmbr1

```
(with -e option)
05:39:40.596069 aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 64: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.100 tell 10.0.0.200, length 46


09:21:01.249929 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.0.100 tell 10.0.0.200, length 46
```

# tcpdump -nn -i veth1

(Nothing, Dropped!, with -e option)

### Test-2: Ping from Server to PC

Working.

### Ping from PC to Server AFTER Test-2

Working.

# tcpdump -nn -e -i enp5s0

```
05:37:10.284850 aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa > bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 102: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 10.0.0.200 > 10.0.0.100: ICMP echo request, id 1591, seq 23140, length 64
05:37:10.285915 bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb > aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 102: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4, 10.0.0.100 > 10.0.0.200: ICMP echo reply, id 1591, seq 23140, length 64
```

### Ping from PC to Server AFTER Test-3 with remove arp

```
sudo arp -d 10.0.0.100 && ping 10.0.0.100
```

Not working again!

Perhaps the cause is that the broadcast does not arrive at veth1 and cannot respond to arp.

Is there a problem with my setup?

Additionally,
Like ping -b 10.0.0.255, protocols other than arp are the same.
Broadcast is not flooding on the bridge.

============================================

Disabling rstp works fine!
What could be the cause?

Comment: You should at least use `-e` with tcpdump to display correctly the VLAN ID if any in the capture, in case it's an encapsulation/decapsulation problem. That's just a hint on how to debug, I have no idea what's the problem.

Comment: I have checked VLAN encapsulation, but it looks fine on tcpdump. Added content. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*STP is buggy in OpenVSwitch*

Sorry, just hit my head against the same rock, and the research I can see across the internet/mailinglists/etc.: there is a problem with Internal (OVSIntPort in ProxMox PVE terms) and OpenVSwitch bridges, the moment you enable *either* for RSTP or STP.

I suspect somehow the interfaces doesn't make it into the forwarding/blockdesignated table/db of the STP/RSTP process, and thus breaks communications.

I *DID* noticed that VMs created *after* initialization, are working fine on the exact same vlan tag as the internal network (OVSIntPort) interfaces, as they are happily receiving broadcasts, but NOT the OVSIntPorts ;(